# OnClick event doesn't work in my chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have made a little extension which inserts buttons into the html page and I have inserted `onClick` events on each button, but when i press them they don't work. I have found some topics on this site and a guy was talking about `addEventListener` but i couldn't use it. My code is something like this:

```
var setButton = "<button type='button' id='setter2' onclick=Set_one(this.id)>set</button>";
var str = getRow.insertCell(-1);
str.innerHTML = setButton;
```

Comment: Is the function `Set_one` exists?

Comment: Is this from a content script or a different part of the extension?

Comment: yes, Set_one exists, and it is in the same content.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Chrome extensions, inline code is [forbidden](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution). You cannot use `onclick` attribute at all for extension scripts, and CSP [cannot be relaxed](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#relaxing-inline-script).

You will have to use `addEventListener` to make it work. It's not hard, and covered in the documentation linked above.

```
var setButton = "<button type='button' id='setter2' onclick=Set_one(this.id)>set</button>";
var str = getRow.insertCell(-1);
str.innerHTML = setButton;
document.getElementById("setter2").addEventListener("click", function() {
  Set_one(this.id);
});
```

It's even better though if you don't use `innerHTML` assignment and directly create/append elements:

```
var setButton = document.createElement("button");
    setButton.textContent = "set";
    setButton.id = "setter2";
    setButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
      Set_one(this.id);
    });
getRow.insertCell(-1).appendChild(setButton);
```

Comment: second code works but when i press it, the page reloads

Comment: i added setButton.type = "button"; and this helped